# popup-kill-ring and multiple-cursors

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm an avid user of both [`popup-kill-ring`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/popup-kill-ring.el) and [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el), however, the default behaviour when using the former while the latter is active is not to my liking.

`popup-kill-ring` provides a popup menu to select an item from the kill-ring for insertion. The default behaviour when multiple (virtual) cursors exist is to select the item for each cursor individually. Typically I want to insert the selected item at all cursor positions.

Anyone know a solution which allows for the desired behaviour?

Comment: Does your `popup-kill-ring` have a *paste* function name that you can add to `mc--default-cmds-to-run-for-all`?  And you can check to make sure that *paste* function is not in the list of `mc--default-cmds-to-run-once`.

Comment: You may also want to check your `mc/list-file` to see if you inadvertently added the *paste* function to run once.  Note:  your *paste* function may not be called "paste" -- I'm just using that to describe the general concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally we could have added the command which inserts the item from popup (`popup-kill-ring-select`) to `mc/cmds-to-run-for-all` which would have caused the command to run for all cursors but this was not working. Other option we have is to write a custom function which if multiple-cursors are active inserts currently selected item in the popup menu for each cursor otherwise fallbacks to default command. Here is what I came up with

```
(defun my-default-popup-kill-ring-behviour ()
  "Switch to default `popup-kill-ring' behavior"
  (interactive)
  (define-key popup-kill-ring-keymap "\r" 'popup-kill-ring-select)
  (let ((m (with-no-warnings menu)))
    (when m
      (popup-delete m)))
  (mc/execute-command-for-all-cursors 'popup-kill-ring)
  (define-key popup-kill-ring-keymap "\r" 'mc-popup-kill-ring-insert))

(defun mc-popup-kill-ring-insert()
  "Insert the selected text at all cursors"
  (interactive)
  ;; If multiple cursor mode is active
  (when multiple-cursors-mode
    ;; Extract the currently selected text from the popup menu
    ;; copied from `popup-kill-ring-select'
    (let* ((m (with-no-warnings menu))
           (item (popup-item-value-or-self (nth (popup-cursor m) (popup-list m))))
           ;; Item is just the text shown in popup not the text actually killed
           ;; following code retrieves the killed text
           (num (popup-kill-ring-get-index item))
           (text (when num
                   (nth num kill-ring)))
           ;; Fake command to insert the kill text
           (command (lambda ()
                      (interactive)
                      (when text
                        (insert text)))))
      ;; Execute the command for each fake cursor
      (save-excursion
        (mc/execute-command-for-all-fake-cursors command))))
  ;; Finally execute the command for current cursor
  (call-interactively 'popup-kill-ring-select))

(define-key popup-kill-ring-keymap "\r" 'mc-popup-kill-ring-insert)
(define-key popup-kill-ring-keymap (kbd "C-<return>") 'my-default-popup-kill-ring-behviour)


(global-set-key (kbd "M-y") 'popup-kill-ring)
```

Now you can bind this command to the desired keybinding, below I bind it to `enter`

```
(define-key popup-kill-ring-keymap "\r" 'mc-popup-kill-ring-insert)
```

To switch to default behaviour after starting `popup-kill-ring` you can use the command `my-default-popup-kill-ring-behviour` command I am binding it to `C-RET`

```
(define-key popup-kill-ring-keymap (kbd "C-<return>") 'my-default-popup-kill-ring-behviour)
```

Comment: One bug: After insertion is finished only the "active" cursor is placed _behind_ the inserted text. The others "mark" the inserted text but are located just _before_ the inserted text.

Comment: Updated the answer should be better now

Comment: Now it works correctly. You have already answered my question and provided a nice solution. :-) Thanks for that! Let me expand the challenge a little bit: Your solution relies on putting `popup-kill-ring` in the `cmds-to-run-once` list. However, it would be nicer to either hit (for example) `C-RET` and insert the current item at all cursors [the functionality provided by your existing function] or `RET` and get a popup for each (virtual) cursor individually [this would be a new function I guess]. Is this something easily achievable?

Comment: I guess that can be done, I will update the answer when I get some time

Comment: @elemakil I have updated the answer, I have not tested it throughly but it worked for me

Comment: Works nicely! I have not encountered a bug so far. Thanks again for helping! :-)